# ASPX website resource token expires, and the page becomes unavailable

Tags: asp.net, curl, python-requests

I am trying to make a periodic balance logger, which logs the current balance of my electricity meter (yes, we have prepaid electric bills here now), like hourly or something. Since I want to find the peak usage hours, and reduce the usage.

It's on their [website](https://nbpdcl.co.in/(S(kpoqs42krzjlg3dnd53gpygo))/frmAdvBillPaymentAll.aspx) (NOTE: this will probably not open by now, and show the error I am having). I entered the details, pressed on the get current balance button, and copied the cURL request using Chrome DevTools.
Running it returns the html web page, which contains what I am looking for in a `input` named `ctl00$MainContent$txtCurrentblnce`, and I can get that easily.

But the problem arrives after a few minutes, the web page returned is `The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable`

[Error's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVyTZ.png)

If I again visit the homepage and follow the links to balance page, and copy a new cURL request, it works! Using diff between those two texts, the only difference is that `(S(kpo....))` part in the url. It Apparently **changes** on each visit to `https://nbpdcl.co.in/`, though remains same if page is reloaded. But after a few minutes, it invalidates and the error is thrown. It seems like some session token, and each token has a lifetime, after which, it can be never used again?

To solve this, I sent a HEAD request to `https://nbpdcl.co.in/` and get the response headers' Location property, and by splitting, I get that session token thing, which is a newly generated token

```py
session_token = requests.head('https://nbpdcl.co.in/',verify=False).headers['Location'].split("/")[1]
```

I used curlconvertor to convert cURL to python requests code, and then used that `session_token` for the `request url`, but it still returned the Resource moved Error. And also, that `token` also doesn't work when pasted into browser (says the same resource moved)

```py
response = requests.post(
    f'https://nbpdcl.co.in/{session_token}/frmAdvBillPaymentAll.aspx',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
    verify=False,
)
```

Another elegant finding, let's say I visit the homepage, it will show a brand new `token` in the address bar. I use that in the `request url`, it won't work. But if I did the thing in browser (manually check the balance, and it appears on my screen), *the **same** code and the same **url** and the same **token** work as normal*

So my question is how can I make this persistence, since I want to set up a server with cronjob, which logs at each hour or so, and then I will code up some API and an App and can be used to view the generated graph. And I think it's not a good Idea to change url every few minutes manually, and in that case it would nice to log it myself each hour